# Adding different logo on different wordpress pages

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

i'm a beginner in code and even if people have probably answered this question i don't know how to implement it in my case...

in my wordpress, i have a woocommerce integrated and i would like to display a different header logo then the home page.

i have found the place where it is called but i dont know how to implement it correctly and not scrap all the code.

i would probably want something like this

```
    <?php if (isset($class) && $class == 'woocommerce'): ?>
    <img src="images/logo-with-white-text" />
<?php else: ?>
    <img src="images/logo-with-dark-text" />
<?php endif; ?>
```

implemented in this code from my theme

```
<!-- START LOGO -->
<div id="logo" class="<?php echo $width_tagline ?>" >

    <?php
    if( yit_get_option( 'header-custom-logo' ) == 'yes' && yit_get_option( 'header-custom-logo-image' ) != '' ) : ?>
        <a id="logo-img" href="<?php echo home_url() ?>" title="<?php bloginfo( 'name' ) ?>">
            <?php $size = @getimagesize(yit_get_option( 'header-custom-logo-image' )); ?>
            <img class="no-dark" src="<?php echo yit_ssl_url( yit_get_option( 'header-custom-logo-image' ) ) ?>" <?php if( yit_get_option( 'logo-retina-url' ) ): ?>data-at2x="<?php echo yit_ssl_url( yit_get_option( 'logo-retina-url' ) ) ?>"<?php endif ?>title="<?php bloginfo( 'name' ) ?>" alt="<?php bloginfo( 'name' ) ?>" <?php if( !empty($size) && isset($size[3] ) ) echo $size[3] ?> />

            <?php if ( 'yes' == YIT_Layout()->enable_dark_header ) : ?>
                <?php $size = @getimagesize(yit_get_option( 'header-dark-custom-logo-image' )); ?>
                <img class="only-dark" src="<?php echo yit_ssl_url( yit_get_option( 'header-dark-custom-logo-image' ) ) ?>" title="<?php bloginfo( 'name' ) ?>" alt="<?php bloginfo( 'name' ) ?>" <?php if( !empty($size) && isset($size[3] ) ) echo $size[3] ?> />
            <?php endif; ?>

        </a>
    <?php else : ?>
        <a id="textual" href="<?php echo home_url() ?>" title="<?php echo str_replace( array( '[', ']' ), '', bloginfo( 'name' ) ) ?>">
            <?php echo yit_decode_title( get_bloginfo( 'name' ) ) ?>
        </a>
    <?php endif ?>

    <?php

       if( yit_get_option( 'header-logo-tagline' ) == 'yes' ):
        $class = array();
        if ( strpos( get_bloginfo( 'description' ), '|') ) $class[] = 'multiline';
        if ( yit_get_option('header-logo-tagline-mobile') == 'no' ) $class[] = 'hidden-xs';
        $class = ! empty( $class ) ? ' class="' . implode( $class, ' ' ) . '"' : '';
        ?>
        <?php yit_string( "<p id='tagline'{$class}>", yit_decode_title( get_bloginfo( 'description' ) ), '</p>' );?>
    <?php endif ?>

</div>
<!-- END LOGO -->
```

I hope someone will be kind enough to help me out on this one!

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can think of collecting all the page slug as key and all image urls as value in an array and for every key you can display a separate image.

Comment: You can install  ACF plugin and then create a custom image field for all page. and you can call image. https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/

Answer (score 0):

My way doing this

```
<a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>" class="logo_link">
    <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/images/logo.png" data-src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/images/logo-wc.png" alt="" class="logo"> 
</a>

<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        if($('body').hasClass('woocommerce')) {
            $('.logo_link img').attr('src', $(this).data('src'));
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If woocommerce is installed and activated you can do this

```
<?php if(is_woocommerce()){ ?>
  <img src="images/logo-with-white-text" />
<?php }else{ ?>
  <img src="images/logo-with-white-text" />
<?php } ?>
```